# Is there a way to neutralize aluminum hydroxide in pool water?

Tags: water-treatment

Pool water sat unfiltered for 12 months with heavy leaf debris. Once manual removal was completed a variety of chemicals were introduced. In particular alum powder. This alum powder has decomposed into sulfuric acid H2SO4 and aluminum hydroxide Al(OH)3. Aluminum hydroxide is a colloid that remains in suspension, producing a cloudy effect.

Is there a way to neutralize this effect so that the suspended particles drop and water clarity is regained?

Comment: Dissolution would probably mean it is not pool water anymore. // Mechanical filtration // water replacement

Comment: @Poutnik something about the way the problem is formulated suggests this is homework and has a tidy answer involving chemistry. Could be wrong though.

Comment: @BuckThorn It is a followup question to [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/167848/why-would-alum-powder-stay-suspended-in-pool-water-instead-if-sinking-like-its-s), Not sure about being a HW, seems like a desperate pool keeper throwing in water whatever was sitting on the shelf.

Answer (score 3):

Use a good pool filter to remove the suspended $\ce{Al(OH)3}$. As you state, they're fine particles, and should glom onto (technical word for "adsorb to") the diatomaceous earth... *eventually*.

Aluminum hydroxide is *quite* stable, and dries out to aluminum oxide, $\ce{Al2O3}$, which is **very** stable. $\ce{Al2O3}$ (sapphire and ruby, i.e., corundum) lasts millions of years, and any chemical that *could* break down $\ce{Al(OH)3}$ or $\ce{Al2O3}$ is *not* something in which you want to swim!